# What word describes knowledge interesting for more than one field?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

What word describes the below definition best?

A knowledge which is interesting from more than one field point of view.

Would polyvalent suit this definition?

Comment: What audience are you trying to reach? Because I have a rather good vocabulary and I had no idea that word could be used that way.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: researchers of various fields.

Comment: If any of them are chemists or physicists, I would not advise that; honestly, I'm not sure it's a good idea to throw around six-dollar words like that anyway. Just express what you're trying to say as plainly and simply as possible.

Answer (score 1):

For the information of future readers:

'Polymath' or 'Renaissance Man' would correctly describe a *person* with knowledge of interest to more than one field.

To describe the knowledge itself, you might choose the adjective **multidisciplinary**. Multidisciplinary knowledge is of interest to people from more than one field.

Answer (score 0):

## 'Polymath' or 'Renaissance Man'

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/polymath):

> Polymath: a person of encyclopedic learning

and from [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/renaissance-man):

> Renaissance man: ( sometimes lowercase ) a present-day man who has acquired profound knowledge or proficiency in more than one field